# Magento 1.9 Why checkout_cart_product_add_after observer is not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, magento-community

I'm trying to execute the following Method with the Observer in my Magento module. But it isn't working and I don't know why.

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <TimgMage_CustomAddToCart>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </TimgMage_CustomAddToCart>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <TimgMage_CustomAddToCart>
        <class>TimgMage_CustomAddToCart_Model</class>
      </TimgMage_CustomAddToCart>
    </models>
    <events>
      <!-- START: Add to cart actions -->
      <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
          <timgmage_customaddtocart_model_observer>
            <class>TimgMage_CustomAddToCart_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>checkoutCartProductAddAfter</method>
            <type>singleton</type>
          </timgmage_customaddtocart_model_observer>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

And the observer

```
<?php

    class TimgMage_CustomAddToCart_Model_Observer
    {

        public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

            Mage::log('Entered to checkoutCartProductAddAfter.', null, 'timgmage.log');

            /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
            $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                $item = $item->getParentItem();
            }

            // Discounted 25% off
            $percentDiscount = 0.25;

            // This makes sure the discount isn't applied over and over when refreshing
            $specialPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice() - ($item->getOriginalPrice() * $percentDiscount);

            // Make sure we don't have a negative
            if ($specialPrice > 0) {
                $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please anybody can help me.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in your log file? Please try the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` instead.

Comment: Thanks @RickyOdinMatthews. I am new with magento and I don't know where is the log file in production. 

I tested it. But it's occurring nothing. It's not changing the price.

Comment: Log file will appear in /var/log/ will post an answer that may help you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

1) Please replace your module name from `TimgMage_CustomAddToCart` to `Timgmage_Customaddtocart`.

2) There are many errors in your config.xml, please update it with :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Timgmage_Customaddtocart>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Timgmage_Customaddtocart>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <timgmage_customaddtocart> //not with an uppercase
                <class>Timgmage_Customaddtocart_Model</class>
            </timgmage_customaddtocart>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after> //Im not sure for this event !
                <observers>
                    <timgmage_customaddtocart_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>timgmage_customaddtocart/observer</class>
                        <method>checkoutCartProductAddAfter</method>
                    </timgmage_customaddtocart_observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
    <frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` instead

Try this code:

```
<?php

class TimgMage_CustomAddToCart_Model_Observer
{

    public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $quoteItems = $quote->getItems();

    foreach ($quoteItems as $_item) {
       echo $_item->getId();
    }

  }
}
```

Quick debugging, this should echo out the cart product ids at top of page. You need to edit each quote item then call `$quote->save();` at the end.